# IPv4, IPv6 and IPTables

Tags: ipv6, iptables, ipv4

I have just recently learned that even if I block all traffic to my webserver using *iptables* it is still vulnerable to external attacks via IPv6. In my understanding, this renders *iptables*-only firewalling useless (or am I wrong?)... That being, What security measures should I take into account to protect a webserver from attacks conducted through IPv6?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two basic options:

- Disable ipv6
- Create  a firewall configuration for ipv6 using `ip6tables`.

A basic guide to disabling ipv6 is [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-how-to-disable-the-ipv6-protocol.html), <strike>although I'm betting a `rmmod ipv6` will do the trick.</strike>

You could use any existing iptables scripts you have as a basis for an "ip6tables" script.  The following should tell ip6tables to lockdown all ipv6 (nothing in, out, or routed):

```
ip6tables -F
ip6tables -P INPUT DROP
ip6tables -P OUTPUT DROP
ip6tables -P FORWARD DROP
```

Comment: Disabling IPv6 doesn't seem like a good option now that it is becoming the Internet's standard way of addressing... Anyway, is there any simple way of achieving that in Ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: @NetStudent: There is... but what's wrong with `ip6tables`?

Comment: Sounds like you basically need to mirror your ipv4 configuration to ipv6.

Comment: `rmmod ipv6` won't do the trick; Linux will automatically load it again when a program attempts to create an IPv6 socket. (That's even assuming `ipv6` is a module, and not compiled into kernel.)

Comment: @ultrasawblade: Yes, I think that is what I need then...

Comment: Does disabling IPv6 address guarantees it against IPv6 attacks?